Where is avatar stats of Tiamat in 2e (the guardian in the Cave of Greed)
In Planescape, Tiamat is cited as the guardian of the passage to the second layer of Baator. In the adventure Fires of Dis, page 33, there is the following description: "Tiamat’s a power, and
powers can’t be disturbed if they don’t wish to be." If it is a power, it can use avatars. But I don't know where to find its stats. The only description I found was in Forgotten Realms book, Draconomicon, page 58, it is there like a unique monster, but the description allows it be used as an avatar: "Tiamat the Chromatic Dragon is similar in nature to Bahamut; nobody knows for sure  whether she is a natural creature, the Queen of Evil Dragons, a demon, or a deity of some kind." So, aside Takhisis avatar and this one for Forgotten Realms, is there stats for Tiamat's avatar?

Monster Mythology
Published by TSR in 1992. Specifically, page 107.
